# DecimalFormatSymbols with Locale

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, locale

For the code below I get a different result when I run it like this, and when I run it inside a Tomcat web app.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.language"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.country"));
    System.out.println(Locale.getDefault(Category.DISPLAY));
    System.out.println(Locale.getDefault(Category.FORMAT));

    Locale l = new Locale("de", "DE");
    System.out.println(l.getDisplayLanguage());
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(l);
    System.out.println(dfs.getDecimalSeparator());

    l = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("de").setRegion("DE").build();
    System.out.println(l.getDisplayLanguage());
    dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(l);
    System.out.println(dfs.getDecimalSeparator());
}
```

Standalone result (expected):

```
en
US
en_US
en_US
German
,
German
,
```

In Tomcat:

```
en
US
en_US
en_US
German
.
German
.
```

Can someone suggest what else influences DecimalFormatSymbols (and NumberFormat for that matter) that it doesn't use the locale provided.
I'm using JDK 1.8 with language level 1.7.

EDIT: This only happens when Tomcat runs in Eclipse. Eclipse/OSGi seems to interfere with the locale-based formatting, but only in a specific situation.

Comment: Are you running it in Tomcat on the same machine, using the same JRE?

Comment: Yes. Both is running inside Eclipse, inside the same project.

Comment: Have you tries Locale l = Locale.GERMANY, too?

Comment: It makes no difference, plus the real code should (and did) work with arbitrary locales.

Comment: Try using this instead: `DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(l)`.

Comment: Thank you, JoD. Unfortunately it did not make a difference in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat our ENV setting might have an issue i see it from the post [here](http://lessysblog.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-force-tomcat-to-run-with-correct.html).

Try starting the tomcat as suggested in the above post with the following params set as a batch file:

```
-Duser.timezone=Europe/Berlin
-Duser.country=DE
-Duser.language=de
```

Comment: The idea is to use different locales at runtime, no matter what the startup setting is.